# Project Catalyst Voting, did not save QR code, but have transaction ID and Pin, can I use this?

Tags: voting

Is there a way to use any information from the project catalyst registration voting transaction ID, instead of the QR code, say if you lost the QR code?

Assume the pin is known.

The transaction ID metadata looks like the following.

```
{
   1: "103a3919a376ca98431c871d7f....fbceab46732e9d4a3c1e5a87995e6ed1786",
   2: "ef36ce85e2967d96db6c26.....29eb132b0df06393b29f790b26a97da90",
   3: "e1916b5b1df589d4a70e5ebde9fc71ea10.....4cab8b8a329b1625620",
   4: 47594896
}


{
   1: "f182e4faa36097d42360416b6d5136e.....a1a535ab6f822293046e5fe426dc37a68557d41da0ac08794b0820addad359299316fd3674a66bced33f95056d07"
}
```

Answer (score 2):

No, the transaction only contains the public key, and the pin code is used to decrypt the private key from the QR code. If you don't have the QR code, you don't have the private key.

Comment: Thank you Samuel